# How to reconcile Apollos caching policy with Reacts component approach?

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-query

I am having trouble understanding how the Apollo caching policy adheres to the react component-based coding style.

In the Apollo caching guide it is strongly recommended to use either `refetchQueries` or do a cache `update`. Both methods require certain knowledge about the usage of other queries in the application. Not only do they require knowledge, but the queries also need to be imported to make cache updates work properly.

In my opinion, components should be able to exist independently of each other and shouldn't directly trigger changes in sibling components.

---

My hardest struggle is, that there seems to exist no intended functionality that allows one to invalidate parts of the cached data depending on a match function or the `__typename` property.
Coming from *react-query* this seems kind of odd. In react-query there exists the possibility to invalidate queries based on prefix matches and I assumed similar behavior is part of Apollo.